# print array value to txt

Tags: php, arrays

I write a program that have array printed in `txt` file:

```
$dataset   = array();
$dataset[] = array('A','B','C','D');
$dataset[] = array('A','D','C');
$dataset[] = array('B','C');
$dataset[] = array('A','E','C');
$arrLength=count($dataset);
for($x=0;$x<$arrLength;$x++){
        file_put_contents ('filename.txt', implode(',',$dataset[$x])."\n", FILE_APPEND);   
}
```

The code above will produce a `txt` file:

```
A,B,C,D
A,D,C
B,C
A,E,C
```

but when I try to to print array from `DB` to `txt` by adopting the previous code, it doesn't give me desired output. Here is my code:

```
$result=array();
        $key='sub';
        foreach($this->Click_model->getClickStream() as $row)
        {

            $result[$row['id_click']]['sub'][]=  $row['id_kampanye'].$row['code'];
            $newResult=array_column($result,$key);
            file_put_contents ('datasetArray.txt', print_r($newResult, true));

            $arrLength=count($newResult);
            for($x=0;$x<$arrLength;$x++){

                file_put_contents ('dataset.txt', implode(',',$newResult[$x])."\n", FILE_APPEND);


            }

        }
```

The code above give me `txt` file like below:

```
17p3
17p3,16visitor
17p3,16visitor
5visitor
17p3,16visitor
5visitor,18p3
17p3,16visitor
5visitor,18p3,15visitor
17p3,16visitor
```

and the array from `$newResult` is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 17p3
            [1] => 16visitor
            [2] => 15visitor
            [3] => 17p3
            [4] => 5visitor
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5visitor
            [1] => 18p3
            [2] => 15visitor
            [3] => 5visitor
            [4] => 18p3
            [5] => 10visitor
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15visitor
            [1] => 15visitor
            [2] => 15visitor
            [3] => 15visitor
            [4] => 15visitor
            [5] => 15visitor
            [6] => 15visitor
            [7] => 15visitor
            [8] => 15visitor
        )
}
```

My expected output:

```
17p3,16visitor,15visitor,17p3,5visitor
5visitor,18p3,15visitor,5visitor,18p3,10visitor
15visitor,15visitor,15visitor,15visitor,15visitor,15visitor,15visitor,15visitor,15visitor
```

Please help me, I don't know what's wrong with my code.

Comment: here what is your problem ?

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: try to use the for loop outside the foreach loop

Comment: @jothi please recheck my question

Comment: @ManjeetBarnala oh yeah! thank you very much for helping me

Comment: @PhilipusSilaen great:) glad to help you:) now you can accept my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for loop outside the foreach loop, Will work for you..

```
<?php 
$result=array();
$key='sub';

foreach($this->Click_model->getClickStream() as $row)
{
    $result[$row['id_click']]['sub'][]=  $row['id_kampanye'].$row['code'];
    $newResult=array_column($result,$key);
    file_put_contents ('datasetArray.txt', print_r($newResult, true));
}

$arrLength=count($newResult);
for($x=0;$x<$arrLength;$x++)
{
    file_put_contents ('dataset.txt', implode(',',$newResult[$x])."\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

based on @Manjeet Barnala comment, i have moved for loop outside the for each loop like below

```
$result=array();
        $key='sub';
        foreach($this->Click_model->getClickStream() as $row)
        {

            $result[$row['id_click']]['sub'][]=  $row['id_kampanye'].$row['code'];
            $newResult=array_column($result,$key);
            file_put_contents ('datasetArray.txt', print_r($newResult, true));

            $arrLength=count($newResult);


        }


for($x=0;$x<$arrLength;$x++){

                    file_put_contents ('dataset.txt', implode(',',$newResult[$x])."\n", FILE_APPEND);


                }
```

Comment: glad to help you dear :)